# What counts towards structure exploration progress?

Tags: starfield

When finding structures on a planet, I tend to try and complete them, as I do not know when I might return. Often when I feel I have cleared the structure, facility or base I look for somewhere new to go.

However when I opened my map I saw despite my efforts I was only 60% complete.

[image: Deserted ecliptic garrison (partially explored 60%)]

What things count towards the exploration percentage of specific places on a planet?

I would assume opening crates and eliminating hostiles, but I'd like to know what I should be looking out for whilst exploring.

Comment: I had a partially explored cave once. I think it's just a matter of looting the key "containers" in the area. I'm assuming that would be the "boss" character or final chest that usually contains epic/legendary item(s). In my case, a dung pile.

Comment: For natural land forms it involves scanning features. It will include a counter usually -- eg (1/2) -- to indicate how many features you've scanned out of the total. I've never run into a 'partially explored' facility so I don't know if there's a similar mechanic there.